# Find the smallest even value of $m$ so that $\mathrm{lcm}(48,180,m)=2160.$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, least-common-multiple

> Find the smallest even value of $m$ so that $\mathrm{lcm}(48,180,m)=2160.$

Can anyone solve this? It's similar to the one before but I can't seem to get the point.

Comment: Hint: $48=2^4\cdot 3$ and $180= 2^2\cdot 3^2\cdot 5$ and $2160=2^4\cdot 3^3\cdot 5$.  Can you relate the prime factorization of the lcm to the prime factorization of $48,180,m$?

Comment: @ThomasAndrews your edit removed the stipulation that our desired $m$ must be even.  I have since edited that stipulation back in.  Many of the answers below were written during this window of time where that stipulation was missing, but can easily be modified by remembering that an even number must have at least one copy of $2$ as a prime factor.

Comment: Whoops, my apologies!

Answer (score 3):

Note that 
$$48=2^4\cdot 3^1,\quad 180=2^2\cdot 3^2\cdot 5^1,\quad 2160=2^4\cdot 3^3\cdot 5^1.$$ Hence, if $m=2^a\cdot 3^b\cdot 5^c$ with $a,b,c\geq 0$ (no prime $p>5$ divides $m$, why?)
$$\mbox{lcm}(48,180,m)=2^{\max(4,a)}\cdot 3^{\max(2,b)}\cdot 5^{\max(1,c)}=2^4\cdot 3^3\cdot 5^1= 2160.$$
Can you take it from here?

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Write the prime factorization of each of the numbers in the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this $$lcm(a,b,c) = lcm(lcm(a,b),c).$$

So $$2160 = lcm(lcm(48,180),m) = lcm(720,m)$$

Now, you can see as follows: $2160 = 2^43^35$, and $720=2^43^25$, then the smallest even number $m$ is $2\times 3^3=54$.

Comment: Sorry, I accidentally edited out the condition that $m$ must be even

Comment: Ok, done. Thanks you,

Answer (score 0):

$2160=2^4\times 3^3\times 5$

$48=2^4\times 3$ and $180=2^2\times 3^2 \times 5$

To have $\text{LCM}(48,180,x)=2160$ you just need $x=3^3=27$

As the request is for an even number you must take $2\times 27=54$

Hope this helps